# Processing P3D: seperate object instances acting dependent... why?

Tags: object, 3d, processing

Working on learning P3D and improving my OOP. I have 2 instances of class Box (see below) and Box2 is acting dependent on Box 1(the x and y 0's of Box 2are considered the coords of Box 1, including when I change x). Im thinking it may be related to using translate, but I dont know an alternative. Code Below.

```
Box Box1;
Box Box2;
int boxXM;

void setup() {
  size(1000, 500, P3D);
  fill(250, 0, 0);
  Box1 = new Box(160, 160, 0, 0, 0);
  Box2 = new Box(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}

void draw() {
  background(200);

  Box1.display();
  Box1.move();

  Box2.display();
  Box2.move();
}

void keyPressed() {
  if (key == 'a') {
    boxXM = 1;
  } else if (key == 'd') {
    boxXM = 2;
  } else {
    boxXM = 0;
  }
}

void keyReleased() {
  boxXM = 0;
}

class Box {
  float boxX;
  float boxY;
  float boxRY;
  float boxRX;
  float boxDist;

  Box(float boxX, float boxY, float boxRY, float boxRX, float boxDist) {
    this.boxX = boxX;
    this.boxY = boxY;
    this.boxRY = boxRY;
    this.boxDist = boxDist;
    this.boxRX = boxRX;
  }

  void display() {
    translate(boxX, boxY, boxDist);
    rotateY(boxRY);
    rotateX(boxRX);
    box(160);
  }
  
  void move() {
    if (boxXM == 1) {
      boxX -= 5;
    }
    if (boxXM == 2) {
      boxX += 5;
    } else {
    }
  }
}
```

I tried doing the way I change X, nothing changed. Dont know any other way, I want the instances to act independently.

Answer (score 0):

You have a single global variable, `boxXM`. When you call `Box::move()` on each box, each looks at the single global variable, `boxM`. Therefore each does the same movement.